# Apple Watch 1st Gen serial number and pairing issue

Tags: apple-watch

I am trying to get the serial number of my Apple Watch 1st gen watch.

I can’t get it off the back as wear has scraped it off over time.

I thought I would try and get it off the watch itself in settings, but I can’t pair it to my iPhone 11 (running iOS 14.1). Every time I try to pair, my iPhone tells me I need to have the latest version of iOS on my iPhone. Which I have.

Is there any way I can get the serial number without pairing?

Or is there a way to help me pair it to get the number?

Comment: Did you ever upgrade the OS on the watch?  What version is it running?

Comment: Are you following these instructions?

Comment: I did but stopped using it for a while then tried to update but it’s not allowing me. I updated my phone as the process instructed but then it wouldn’t allow me to go further as it said I needed to update my phone (despite being on the latest version)

Comment: Can you get into the settings of the watch (tap the crown)?

Comment: @Allan No, I can’t use the basic functions of the watch, it is asking me to pair and I can’t, I can’t get to the Home Screen, apps etc as it’s acting like a watch that’s not been set up

Comment: It’s like it’s been reset and I can’t get passed the Pair screen

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your phone?

Comment: I have, it was rebooted as part of the phone update too

Answer (score 0):

It's under *Settings* on the Apple Watch.

Tap *General* then *About*.  Scroll down until you see Serial Number and the IMEI (where applicable).  If it's paired to your phone, it's under *General → About* in the "My Watch" App.

[image]

[How to find the serial number or IMEI for your Apple Watch](https://support.apple.com/HT204520)

Comment: I can’t pair the watch so can not access this unless it’s paired.

Comment: @UIO There are instructions *for the Apple Watch itself.*  It's the very first sentence.  I included the paired info for others who might come across this post.

Comment: I can’t use the watch, it isn’t paired to my phone and to use it fully it seems to be a requirement. I can’t access any menus etc I just get pairing instructions.

Comment: That would have been critical info to have put in the initial question, don't you agree @UIO?

Comment: The third paragraph in my post, that is what I tried to explain there.